# Getting error in alter statements in azure sql managed instance

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance

Hi i have a azure sql managed instance and when i execute the below query i get the error as

The operation cannot be performed on database "" because it is involved in a database mirroring session or an availability group. Some operations are not allowed on a database that is participating in a database mirroring session or in an availability group.

Query :

```
alter database <dbname> set ENABLE_BROKER with ROLLBACK immediate
```

how do i solve this?

I tried the below

```
ALTER DATABASE [dbName] REMOVE SECONDARY ON SERVER [serverName]
```

but it gives me error as This feature is not supported through T-SQL on SQL Database Managed Instance.

Comment: Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288542/operation-cannot-be-performed-on-database-because-it-is-involved-in-a-database-m

Comment: What Service Tier is your Managed Instance?   A Premium/Business Critical uses Availability Groups under the covers to provide redundancy which may be a factor here. You might try changing the tier to Standard/General Purpose to then retry the command and see if that works.

Comment: @MartinCairney I am in general purpose

Comment: Then check whether the issue identified by @Leon is the culprit

Comment: @LeonYue Yes geo replication is on. But how do i drop the replicated database? I have edited what i tried as per the link suggested by you

Comment: @MartinCairney Yes geo replication is on. But how do i drop the replicated database? I have edited what i tried as per the link suggested by Leon Yue

Comment: @LeonYue yes i tried with admin account and i got the error as This feature is not supported through T-SQL on SQL Database Managed Instance.

Comment: @ashish how about this statement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/remove-a-secondary-replica-from-an-availability-group-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#TsqlProcedure? ALTER statement should be executed on the master database on which the primary database server is located.

Comment: @LeonYue how do i get the availability group name? I dont see Always On High Availability node in object explorer

Comment: @ashish ref here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/view-availability-group-properties-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @LeonYue yes i saw the link but i dont see that node there.

Comment: @ashish I'm sorry I can't test this query for you because I don't have the same environment. Here's the query statement I found: https://dbtut.com/index.php/2019/01/21/how-to-list-availability-group-names-database-names-ips-ports-dns-names-in-sql-server/

Comment: Hi @ashish, did you get any progresses now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell to manage the Geo-Failover Group.  I think you will need to remove the failover group first with [Remove-AzSqlDatabaseInstanceFailoverGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/remove-azsqldatabaseinstancefailovergroup?view=azps-5.3.0) , make you changes and then recreate the Failover Group.

Comment: But how will this solve the issue of what i am trying to achieve that is setting the ENABLE_BROKER with ROLLBACK immediate by altering?

Comment: Once you remove the Failover Group you shouldn't be blocked from running the ALTER as per the initial error message